# Category ID fetched as NULL while adding Item Details using spring boot+JPA+Thymeleafe

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf, h2

Trying to learn spring boot.
I am trying to add a entity ITEM_DETAILS and CATEGORY_ID is set as foreign key in that entity.
But while submitting the form the CATEGORY_ID is fetched as NULL and the same in getting inserted in DB (H2)
Below is how the category details are populated in the Add Item page

```
<div class="mb-3">
            <label for="categoryID" class="form-label">Gender
            </label>
            <select class="form-select" name="categoryID">
                <option selected>Select Category</option>
                <option value="1">Electronic</option>
                <option value="2">House Hold</option>
                <option value="3">Grocery</option>
                <option value="4">Official</option>
                <option value="5">Kids</option>
                <option value="6">Miscellaneous</option>
                <option value="7">Family</option>
                <option value="9">Miscellaneous</option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

Below is the code block for associating CATEGORY_ID as foreign key in ItemDetails entity class

```
@ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CATEGORY_ID")
    private Category category;
    
    @Column(name = "ITEM_NAME")
    private String itemName;

    @Column(name = "ITEM_DESCRIPTION")
    private String itemDesc;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "itemDetails")
    private Set<ExpenseDetails> expenseDetails=new HashSet<>();
        

    public ItemDetails() {
        
    }

    public ItemDetails(int itemId, Category category, String itemName, String itemDesc,
            Set<ExpenseDetails> expenseDetails) {
        super();
        this.category = category;
        this.itemName = itemName;
        this.itemDesc = itemDesc;
        this.expenseDetails = expenseDetails;
    }
```

Below is the code block of Category entity class to create one to many relationship

```
public Category() {
    }

    public Category(int categoryID) {
        super();
        this.categoryID = categoryID;
    }

    public Category(int categoryID, String categoryName, String categoryDesc, Set<ItemDetails> itemDetails) {
        super();
        this.categoryID = categoryID;
        this.categoryName = categoryName;
        this.categoryDesc = categoryDesc;
        this.itemDetails = itemDetails;
    }



    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category")
    private Set<ItemDetails> itemDetails=new HashSet<>();
```

When I print itemDetails after submitting I get all details for the Item but category comes as NULL
This is the controller for adding Item

```
@PostMapping("/saveitem")
    public String saveItemDetails(@ModelAttribute ItemDetails itemDetails){
        System.out.println(itemDetails);
        itemService.saveItem(itemDetails);
        return "redirect:/getallitems";
    }
```

And this is the output I get

```
Hibernate: select c1_0.category_id,c1_0.category_description,c1_0.category_name from category c1_0
ItemDetails{itemId=0, category=null, itemName='Samsung', itemDesc='TV'}
Hibernate: insert into item_details (item_id, category_id, item_description, item_name) values (default, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: select i1_0.item_id,i1_0.category_id,i1_0.item_description,i1_0.item_name from item_details i1_0
```

Would like to understand what I am missing here.

I am expecting to get the category details

Answer (score 0):

I did a mistake. In the select item the name I had given as `categoryID`
Now I have made it category similar to the instance name of Category entity class in Item entity class.
Now it is working fine

```html
<div class="mb-3">
  <label for="categoryID" class="form-label">Gender</label>
  <select class="form-select" name="category">
    <option selected>Select Category</option>
    <option value="1">Electronic</option>
    <option value="2">House Hold</option>
    <option value="3">Grocery</option>
    <option value="4">Official</option>
    <option value="5">Kids</option>
    <option value="6">Miscellaneous</option>
    <option value="7">Family</option>
    <option value="9">Miscellaneous</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Now category is fetched correctly

```
ItemDetails{
  itemId=0,
  category=Category
  [
    categoryID=2,
    categoryName=House Hold,
    categoryDesc=Household Item,
    itemDetails=[]],
    itemName='Bottle ',
    itemDesc='Water Bottle'
  ]
}
```